# How to load fingerprinting js asynchronously and get visitor id

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros, xpcom

I'm using javascript scripting with a legacy version of iMacros (v8.9.7)
And I'm a bit confused about getting fingerprinting JS to work properly.

My use case :
1- load fingerprintingJS from CDN asynchronously
2- store the visitorID into variable

My code :

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm");

    function initFingerprintJS() {
        FingerprintJS.load()
        .then(fp => fp.get())
        .then(result => {
            const visitorId = result.visitorId;
            window.console.log(visitorId);
        });
    }

    const loadScript = (src, async = true, type = "text/javascript") => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const el = window.document.createElement("script");
                const container = window.document.head || window.document.body;

                el.type = type;
                el.async = async;
                el.src = src;

                el.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    resolve({ status: true });
                });

                el.addEventListener("error", () => {
                    reject({
                        status: false,
                        message: `Failed to load the script ${src}`
                    });
                });

                container.appendChild(el);
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    };

    function get_fingerprint() {

        loadScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs@3/dist/fp.min.js")
        .then((data) => {
            window.console.log("Script loaded successfully", data);
            initFingerprintJS();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            window.console.error(err);
        });
    }
    <button onclick="get_fingerprint()">FINGERPRINT</button>
```

when I remove the two Components imports and run the bit of script in the console, everything works. But when it's from iMacros interface, it generates errors

[image: Error]

> GET
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs@3/dist/fp.min.js
> [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0 ms] Script loaded successfully Object { status:
> true } ReferenceError: FingerprintJS is not defined Trace de la pile :
> initFingerprintJS@resource://gre/modules/RemoteAddonsParent.jsm:1102:5
> get_fingerprint/<@resource://gre/modules/RemoteAddonsParent.jsm:1142:9
> Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:932:23
> this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:813:7
> this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm
> -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:747:11

Any helps please

Comment: you're trying to load a modern library in a legacy web context: does it even have support for the JS language features that library needs to start up?

Comment: I tried with another external script with a function inside. Function remains "not defined"

Comment: sounds like you have a problem entirely unrelated to your own code, then. Time to delete this question and do some testing to see what your imacros version even accepts?

Comment: "It" (iMacros v8.9.7 for FF) accepts "everything" the FF JS Runtime Engine accepts and can do... (at least until FF v55.0.3, some Func got broken by FF56...).